# List item record in random order when it gets removed from list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got list view table. Whenever i try to delete the item from the list view table, the order of the list becomes random but then when I add an item into the list, the list is sorted. Whenever the list is deleted, I want the rest of the items to be sorted by the student ID. I have tried and haven't had any luck so far.

StudentOrder.xaml

```
<CollectionViewSource
    Source="{Binding StudentRecords}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

StudentOrder.xaml.cs

```
void StudentOrder_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Shows.OrderCurrent == null)
    {
        Show.OrderPresent = StudentID;
        Show.DataOrder = "StudentID";
        Show.Order();
    }
    else
    {
        if (orderLst != null)
        { 
            Show.Order();
        }
    }
}
```

ShowOrders.cs

```
public override bool Delete()
{
    recordRetriever.StudentOrderRetriever.Delete(_record);
    Record = null;
    Refresh();
    return true;
}

private ObservableCollection<ShowOrder> RandomListSort()
{
    IEnumerable<ShowOrder> arrangeditems = StudentRecords;
    if (Orderreplaced)
    {
        switch (DataOrder)
        {
            default:
                arrangeditems = StudentRecords.OrderBy(s => s.GetType().GetProperty(DataOrder).GetValue(s, null)).ToList();
                break;
        }
    }
    Orderreplaced = false;
    return new ObservableCollection<RandomListSort>(arrangeditems);
}

public override void Refresh()
{
    Refresh();
    StudentRecords = RandomListSort();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why you will call `Refresh()` inside the `Refresh()`? And also what the `Show` is, is it related to `ShowOrders`? If yes, your have sort your student records in `RandomListSort`

Answer (score 0):

There is no property you set for sorting description. If not you are doing it programatically better set it in the XAML it self as shown below.

```
<CollectionViewSource
        Source="{Binding StudentRecords}">
<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="your Propery from bound source" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

For more documentation look into below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you remove any other sorting code you tried on your own. If not remove it and try.

Comment: Yeah tried everything and it didnt work so came here to ask.